# Virtual box isn't booting up the Ubuntu

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I have been using Ubuntu on Virtual Box for six months. But today , when I tried to boot up  Ubuntu,  Vbox showed the following error.

> The configuration constructor in main failed due to a COM error.
> Check the release log of the VM for further details.

> **(VERR_MAIN_CONFIG_CONSTRUCTOR_COM_ERROR).**

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)  
Component: ConsoleWrap  
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I kept trying. But the same error pops up every single time.
What is wrong here ? How do I get my Ubuntu up and running without losing any data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. Turned out , I was using outdated version of VBox. I updated it. Its working now. I haven't lost any data

Comment: you should consider elaborating on your answer so the others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug, I have it as well and it's probably Microsoft screwed things again as they usually do.

I tried everything I could and nothing solved the issue. we'll have to wait for Oracle to fix this I guess.